# Inserted row is not accessible for another connection after transaction commit

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, rabbitmq, masstransit

We have a very weird problem using EF 6 with MSSQL and MassTransit with Rabbit MQ.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Client application inserts a row in database (via EF code first - implicit transaction only in DbContext SaveChanges)
2. Client application publishes Id of the row via MassTransit
3. Windows Service with consumers processes the message
4. Row is not found initially, after a few retries, the row appears

I always thought that after commit the row is persisted and becomes accessible for other connections...

We have ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION on in the database.

What is the reason of this and is there any way to be assured that the row is accessible before publishing the Id to MQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dependent upon another transaction being completed before your event handler can continue, you need to make you read serializable. Otherwise, transactions are isolated from each other and the results of the write transaction are not yet available. Your write may also need to be serializable, depending upon how the query is structured.

Yes, the consumers run that quickly.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, if I make both the insert in client and read in the  consumer serializable, it will work correctly (I mean the row will always be found then)?

Comment: I have set up serializable transactions and will accept if everything seems to work.